# Relate the $k$th singular value of a compact operator $A$ to the tensor-product $A^{\otimes k}$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, tensor-products

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$ be compact and $(\sigma_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a nonincreasing enumeration of the singular values of $A$ counted with multiplicity. By definition, the singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of the square-root $$|A|:=\sqrt{A^\ast A}.$$ Moreover, by the Courant-rayleigh minimax principle, $$\sigma_k=\max_{\substack{U\le(\ker A)^\perp\\\dim U=k}}\min_{\substack{x\in U\\\left\|x\right\|_H=1}}\langle|A|x,x\rangle_H\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N.$$ In particular, $$\sigma_1=\left\||A|\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}=\left\|A\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}\tag2.$$

Now, I wondered whether we are able to relate the $\sigma_k$ to the tensor product $A^{\otimes k}$. By definition, if $L_1\in\mathfrak L(H)$, $L_1\otimes L_2$ is the linearization of $$H^2\ni(x_1,x_2)\mapsto L_1x_1\otimes L_2x_2.\tag3$$ The question is, with which norm (or inner product) we need to endow the space of this operators.

I would like to find a relation of the kind $$\left\|A^{\otimes k}\right\|=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k\tag4.$$

Obviously, if $(e_1,\lambda_1),\ldots,(e_n,\lambda_n)$ are eigenpairs of $A$, then $$A^{\otimes n}\left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^ne_i\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\bigotimes_{i=1}^ne_i\tag5$$ and hence $\left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^ne_i,\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)$ is an eigenpair of $A^{\otimes n}$. The only problem now is that we cannot apply the argumentation above again, unless $A^{\otimes n}$ is again an operator on a Hilbert space.

If I remember correctly, endowing the tensor product of operators with the projective norm and building the completion yields the space of trace-class operators (which is not a Hilbert space), but building the completion with respect to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm yields the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators (which is a Hilbert space). So, I guess the latter is what we need to do.

**EDIT**: Actually, what I'm trying to find is an analogue of [Proposition 3.2.7 in *Random Dynamical Systems*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KCbyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=%22Singular+Values+of+Exterior+Power%22&source=bl&ots=8E2_XBAcTA&sig=ACfU3U1MVsM1LemUm8xX5R0SwwaMFrzBBA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhyvP3xZrpAhWRyqQKHdP2BCMQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Singular%20Values%20of%20Exterior%20Power%22&f=false):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that $A$ is compact.

You cannot expect $(4)$ with $k>1$. It is trivial to construct nonzero $A$ with $\sigma_2=0$. Then, for any norm, you would have $\|A^{\otimes k}\|=0$, so $A^{\otimes k}=0$.

If you use the operator norm, you have 
$$
\|A^{\otimes k}\|=\|A\|^k=\sigma_1^k. 
$$

Comment: Maybe I didn't thought on this well enough. What I'm trying to achieve is the following: If $A^{\wedge k}$ denotes the exterior product, we have $\left\|A^{\wedge k}\right\|=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k$. I was trying to achieve an analogue of this, but with the tensor product instead.

Comment: Or, to better explain what I'm after, see [Proposition 3.2.7 in *Random Dynamical Systems*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KCbyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=%22Singular+Values+of+Exterior+Power%22&source=bl&ots=8E2_XBAcTA&sig=ACfU3U1MVsM1LemUm8xX5R0SwwaMFrzBBA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhyvP3xZrpAhWRyqQKHdP2BCMQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Singular%20Values%20of%20Exterior%20Power%22&f=false). I would like to have an analogue for that (but for general compact operators instead of matrices)

Comment: My current guess is that the problem lies in the fact that the elements of the exterior product are *alternating* forms and hence the largest eigenvalues of $|A|^{\wedge k}$ is $\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k$. In contrast, while $\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k$ is clearly an eigenvalue of $|A|^{\otimes k}$, it's not the largest one, since this would clearly be $\sigma_1^k$. So, we would need to have some kind of "alternating" tensors (if there is something like that). Can you follow me?

Comment: I know very little about all this. But  the exterior product is a quotient of the tensor product. So basically you are looking for a norm on the tensor product that agrees with the quotient norm.

Comment: Unfortunately, me neither. Maybe we can show that there is some kind of closed subspace of the Hilbert-Schmidt tensor product $H^{\otimes2}$ consisting of alternating tensors and we can treat $A^{\otimes2}$ as a bounded linear operator on it so that the largest eiganvalue of $|A|^{\otimes2}$ is $\sigma_1\sigma_2$. With the usual construction, it is clearly $\sigma_1^2$.  I've asked specifically for that there: https://mathoverflow.net/q/359361/91890. So, if you get some ideas ...

Comment: If $A$ is self-adjoint, $A=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_ie_i\otimes e_i$ for some orthonormal system $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $u:=e_k+x$ for some $k\in I$ and $x\in\{\mathbb Re_k\}^\perp$, then $$\langle Au,u\rangle_H=\lambda_k+\langle Ax,x\rangle_H\le\lambda_k+\lambda_{k+1}\left\|x\right\|_H^2=\lambda_k-\lambda_{k+1}+\lambda_{k+1}\left\|u\right\|_H^2.$$ Why is the right-hand side $\le\lambda_k\left\|u\right\|_H^2$? It's claimed in https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/spectral-theory.pdf on page 25 in the 5th displayed equation.

Comment: (I forgot to mention that the $(\lambda_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is nonincreasing)

Comment: The setup there is not what you wrote. There, $I=\mathbb N$, and $P_k$ is onto. So there exists $v\in V$ with $P_kv=e_k$. Since $P_k$ preserves $e_1,\ldots,e_k$, the first $k-1$ coefficients of $v$ are zero, so $v=e_k+\sum_{j>k}\alpha_je_j$. Then $$\langle Av,v\rangle=\lambda_k+\sum_{j>k}\lambda_j|\alpha_j|^2\leq\lambda_k(1+\sum_{j>k}|\alpha_j|^2)=\lambda_k\,\|v\|^2.$$

Comment: The setup is the same. My $u$ is their $v$ and my $x$ is their $w$. But I actually wanted to assume that $x$ is in the orthogonal complement of the subspace $E$ spanned by $e_1,\ldots,e_k$. How does the claim follow from that? I (maybe mistakenly) thought the only thing that matters is $x\in(\mathbb Re_k)^\perp\supseteq E^\perp$.

Comment: It follows as I already wrote.

Comment: I've actually used the fact that $x\in E^\perp$ to obtain $\langle Au,u\rangle_H\le\lambda_k+\lambda_{k+1}\left\|x\right\|^2_H$. And this is clearly $\le\lambda_k(1+\left\|x\right\|_H^2)$. Since I've already remark that $\left\|u\right\|_H^2=1+\left\|x\right\|_H^2$, the claim trivially follows. I'm sorry. Don't know why I didn't saw it in the first place. I've got a related question which you may be able to answer as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3610626/47771. Would be great if you could take a look.

Comment: (Oh, and do you see a reason why they've restricted $V$ to be a subspace of $\mathcal N(T)^\perp$? I don't see any stage where they've used this fact. So, we should be able to conclude that $$\lambda_k=\max_{\substack{V\le H\\\dim V=k}}\inf_{\left\|v\right\|_H=1}\langle Av,v\rangle_H.$$

Comment: On a superficial look, I don't think the condition on the kernel is needed.